# What is better way to draw a custom button?

Tags: ios, button, core-graphics

I need to have a few buttons in my iPhone app (which may be then ported to iPad). I know at least 2 methods for  making such buttons:
1. Using usual UIButton with an image as a background which can be drawn in any graphics editor.
2. Subclassing UIButton and implementing own drawRect: method using CoreGraphics tools.

I don't know why, but I tend to use the second one, since it seems to be more difficult and lower performing.

Am I right thinking that when implementing the button drawing programmatically, it becomes "cross platform" so that you don't need several icons for different resolutions?

If that is really simple icon, some bezier curve or circle filled with color. Will it still preform slower than an image-button?

And does somebody know any tool which has a graphical interface for drawing a vector image, and than converts it to the CoreGraphics code which one can paste into the drawRect: method?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at: http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/paintcode/id507897570

Comment: Oh! That looks awesome. Thank a lot for this link. Do you also use this program?

Comment: I've used the trial (on the website, link via app store) and will buy it when I have the money spare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry for using drawRect. Unlike Windows, iOS caches the results into a bitmap and will only redraw it when the dimensions of the view change (which is what you actually want - since you want to scale it again).

As for a vector app, you can use Opacity. It has an option to export the icon into CoreGraphics source code: http://likethought.com/opacity/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Does it mean that if the button uses background Image, it will redraw the image more often? Or the difference is only at the beginning: CG button is drawn from the code and image button is read from the file, but after that if no changes are done to dimensions of the button, they behave in the same way: just reaing bitmap from the cache?

Comment: Correct. UIView will be redrawn in 2 cases: when explicitly calling setNeedsDisplay or when resizing and contentMode=UIViewContentModeRedraw. It's important to note that just resizing the UIView will NOT generate a call to drawRect unless it follows by a call to setNeedsRedraw OR when contentMode=UIViewContentModeRedraw. For any other case, the OS will simply scale the CACHED bitmap according to the current contentMode.

Comment: Well, answer is pointing to tool that is paid. Not even good one. Try Paintcode, google it.